# NuGet - removing dll from references csproj

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, csproj, nuspec

I have problem with nuget package. I'm creating nupkg from two dlls, but in references after install I need to just one dll. Another one is an dependency of the first one. For me that is no problem that dll i added to references but this is license problem (just one developer license).

Anyone know solution for this problem. I tried add dll to content or tools folder but visual studio still adding file to references...

Comment: You can delete the reference in Solution Explorer, but it still need to be in the bin folder so you can compile. I would add dll in Solution Explorer where the other cs source files are located by using Add Existing and then browse to location of dll.   Then right click on dll and select the Copy property so the dll get copied to the bin folder, but not will not get published.

Comment: How would the project not referencing the dll solve the licensing problem? The dll is still shipped in the package, and distribution is usually the legal part of the license.

Comment: @zivkan It's simple ... One developer is working on functionality using this library. We create a nuget package on our own (non-public) server. Then we attach to the main project only the library we constructed on the main interface, because the purchased one does not meet our full requirements. Nuget should put in Solution Explorer only the one I created ... not bought (I know that I can manually remove it, but then I can opt out of nuget and send zip by e-mail). All in accordance with the license, discussed with the owner. But that's not the problem here.